# How can I find out which theme-colors my views use?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I want to customize the colors of a progress bar. The problem is, that color changes in the XML require API>21 and I want to have minimum API of 18. So, what I already found out is, that the "progress-color" of the progress bar is set by accessing the accent-color from the theme. When overriding the theme like this:

```
<style name="AppTheme.ProgressBar">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

I can easily manipulate the "progress-color".

But now I also want to manipulate the background color of the progress bar. The only thing is, that I don't know which theme-color is accessed by the progress bar to set the background color. Does anyone know how I find out, which theme colors the progress bar is adopting?

Comment: Are you using material or appcompat?

Comment: I'm using AppCompat

Comment: You don't have an high degree of styles below API 21. Check a theme like `Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar` to see if it has some interesting properties to override. At first simply try to apply a background color with `background` style property

Comment: Just as an update for anyone wondering what I did: I created my own layout file for the progress bar :D That is done pretty quickly and then the progress bar is fully customizable. The first approach was just a time waste...